# prepareForSegue for Popover

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have returned to a project to make some minor changes and find that I'm getting a `NSInvalidArgumentException` presenting a popover.  I'm almost certain that this worked previously.  I'm using Xcode 6.3.1 and iOS 8.3 SDK.

I believe the issue is to do with the segue object being sent to prepareForSegue which is a `UIStoryboardPushSegue` - should it not be a `UIStoryboardPopoverSegue` if that is what is defined in the storyboard segue?

The error I'm receiving is `-[UIStoryboardPushSegue popoverController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        DatePickerViewController *vc = (DatePickerViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        [vc setQuestion:self.question];
        [vc setDismissPopoverDelegate:self];

        if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"CompletionDateSegue"])
        {
            [vc.datePicker setDate:self.question.completionDate animated:YES];
            [vc setPropertyName:@"completionDate"];

        }
        else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TargetCompletionDateSegue"])
        {
            [vc.datePicker setDate:self.question.targetCompletionDate animated:YES];
            [vc setPropertyName:@"targetCompletionDate"];
        }

        UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *popoverSegue = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue;
        [popoverSegue.popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 256) animated:YES];
}
```

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: Could you found a solution for this?